# Extend JQueryUI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have an application that has a number of dialogs, both for messages and various inputs.

The main application captures a number of key-presses, including alpha characters, and I need to disable those events whenever ANY dialog is open.

At the moment I have a function that saves the keyboard events, which I call on each dialog's open event, and another function to restore the keyboard events, which I call on each dialog's close event.

It works okay, but it means a lot of duplication, and I also have to remember to add those functions for any new dialog.

It seems to me that there is probably some way to hook into the general dialog code, so that I can automatically call my functions for every dialog that I use.

I haven't really extended anything in JQuery before, so I'm not quite sure where to start.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out.  It's pretty easy really, but I'll post here in case it helps someone else.

Basically you just inherit from the dialog widget, and then override the methods (remembering to call the original).  Here's a simple version of it that just logs console messages on open and close.

```
$.widget("custom.cDialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    open: function () {
        console.log("open");
        return this._super();
    },
    close: function () {
        console.log("close");
        return this._super();
    }
});
```

Hope that helps someone.